# openvpn and DNS

Tags: networking, dns, vpn, openvpn

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 and I have setup an openvpn connection that works fine. Before starting the vpn connection, my ISP DNS is defined in `/etc/resolv.conf` from DHCP:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver isp.x.y.z
```

I have added the followign lines to the openvpn configuration file:

```
up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
```

so the `/etc/resolv.conf` gets updated when I start the vpn connection. When started, it looks like this:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver vpn.x.y.z
nameserver isp.x.y.z
```

with `vpn.x.y.z` the IP of the vpn DNS server; what I wanted. However, the line for my ISP DNS is still there. This causes a problem when running a [DNS leak tests](http://dnsleak.com/) as my ISP DNS gets queried.

So I'm trying to get rid of the entry of my ISP when starting the openvpn connection. It works fine if I remove it manually but I'd like to get this automated. Any suggestion?

Thanks!

Fritz

Comment: Clear the list of DNS Servers defined in your connection profile.

Comment: How? What do you mean by "connection profile"? I have not defined any dns entry anywhere, they are either coming from network manager and dhcp or openvpn.

Comment: Connection profile... go to Network icon in the top panel, choose **Edit Connections...**, find the profile for "Wired Connection"/whatever, go to the IPv4 tab, and clear any list of DNS servers shown there.

Comment: I checked that one already and can confirm I do not have any DNS entry in any NetworkManager connection.  My DNS is defined dynamically via DHCP.

Comment: If you're seeing nameserver isp.x.y.z in resolve.conf, then you're probably not running dnsmasq. What's in your /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf?

Comment: Indeed, I switched off dnsmasq by commenting out the line dns=dnsmasq in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` . I have try both actually; with dnsmasq on, my `/etc/resolv.conf` contains the line `nameserver 127.0.1.1` but still any dns leak test reveals my isp dns

Comment: Test with leaving dnsmasq on/off, and in your network connection profile, go to the IPv4 tab and change `Automatic (DHCP)` to `Automatic (DHCP) addresses only` and then try your leak test.

Comment: It did the trick. I have set the connection to `Automatic (DHCP) addresses only` and dnsmasq on at no leak anymore. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments...

Turn dnsmasq back on, and in your network connection profile, go to the IPv4 tab and change `Automatic (DHCP)` to `Automatic (DHCP) addresses only` and then retry your leak test.