# Fail to set up dns on openvpn

Tags: dns, openvpn

I installed openvpn on Ubuntu 16.04, I can connect to the hosts by the ip address but not using the domain name.

When I try to set up the dns with the command:

```
up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
```

I get the the output

```
up: command not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution add th lines

```
up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
```

to the file /etc/openvpn/client.conf

thanks to the post: [openvpn and DNS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/885497/openvpn-and-dns)